# Where can I get a list of country names in native languages?

Tags: php, list, native, countries

I know that there are lists of country names in various languages available separately, but I would like to have a list of countries where each country is named how the inhabitants of the country call it. I mean the list like:

```
United States of America
Россия
Deutschland
```

I think it would be convenient for website visitors to choose the country name which they know well and also I won't have to store a separate country list for each language on the server - I can always display just this common list.

Is there such a list available on the Internet? Or maybe I can get it out of PHP somehow?

Comment: If you specify the programming language, framework there is a chance that something like this is already built-in.

Comment: Just added to the post, it's PHP.

Comment: The best one I found is here: [http://www.geonames.de/](http://www.geonames.de/), check the source code for that `html select` in the middle of the page. It contains 2 characters country code plus names in native languages with correct diacritic!

Comment: There's an unsorted array with two letter ISO codes in here: https://github.com/nu7hatch/awesome_country_select/blob/master/lib/awesome_country_select.rb ... should be simple enough to convert into however it is needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the wikipedia article

[list of countries and capitals in native languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_and_capitals_in_native_languages).

also

[list of country names in various languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_country_names_in_various_languages).

http://www.omniglot.com/countries/

Comment: Thanks, endonym column is what I need, but still maybe there is a simple list available? Wikipedia gives too many alternative names for the same country, I have no idea which of them is most commonly used. But I guess, maybe I'll hav to compose the full list myself...

Comment: The fourth link i have just added.Check it.

Comment: Great, your last two links are the best.